# How to implement something like Amazon's "Customers who viewed also viewed..."?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, machine-learning, data-mining, recommendation-engine

This may sound very newbie, but I was wondering if there's a simple way to achieve something like Amazon's "Customers who viewed this also viewed..".

Theoretically I know you can do clustering, data mining, etc. to do something like this but I am just working on a ruby-on-rails app and want to incorporate something like this to my already existing app (which uses pgsql), and kind of lost.

I'm not looking for a super-sophisticated solution but just want something simple I can just quickly employ.

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: There are books on "recommender systems", so don't expect a answer in this Q&A format.

Comment: You can start by saving the items a user views into a DB table. Than you could try to get some relations from that table.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon is able to pull this off because they have millions of users and a huge inventory which results in billions of data points. They crunch these data to make sense[user profiles, product profiles, likes, dislikes] and build a recommendation engine to help users discover products and drive sales. It makes sense to them.

Since you're not looking into data science and I have no idea of what all data you collect, you could start off by showing other products purchased by users who bought the specific product. Experiment and A/B test to see what works and what doesn't. Iterate on this, to show products bought by others users matching current users age, gender,nationality etc.

This will not be the recommendation engine that you are expecting but might drive some sales.